# Scrolling through font-weight numerical value

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Back in the days of Firebug, it was possible to scroll through (arrow up/down) the font-weight value with keys only.

Is this possible in Chrome dev tools? I.e. by some key + arrow up increment the value with 100 and arrow down decrement with 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go ;)

You can't scroll the numbers because the value validates strings, not only digits. 
[image]

Comment: Nice one! :) But if `font-weight`already exists, I assume I'd have to rewrite the rule to get the list of values?

Comment: If there is already some value, in order to see the dropdown menu you just need to select all the value and delete it. The dropdown menu will show straight away. 
If you are unsure, just write another `font-weight` rule underneath the current one and use that one.